# How do I join my date and time string together?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to join my date and time string together before running it in date_create_from_format but I keep getting the error **"date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, bool given"** can anyone explain to me what im doing wrong?

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

        //

         $this->validate($request, [
            'event_name' => 'required|string|min:2|max:255',
            'daterange' => 'required',
        ]);
        $time_start = $request->input('start_time');

        $time_end = $request->input('end_time');

        $tempDate = $request->input('daterange');
        $temp2 = str_replace('-', null, $tempDate);
        $temp2 = str_replace('/', '-', $temp2);
        $temp3 = explode('  ', $temp2);

        $merge = $temp3[0]. ' '. $time_start;

        $date1 = date_create_from_format('m-d-Y H:i:s', $merge);
        $date2 = date_create_from_format('m-d-Y H:i:s', $temp3[1]);

        $event = new event([
            'event_name' => $request->input('event_name'),
            'event_desc' => $request->input('event_desc'),
            'event_venue' => $request->input('event_venue'),
            'event_start' => date_format($date1, 'Y-m-d'),
            'event_finish' => date_format($date2, 'Y-m-d'),

            'evcat_id' => $request->input('evcat_id'),
            'user_id' => $request->input('user_id'),
        ]);

        $event->save();
        Session::flash('success', 'Event Created Successfully');
        return redirect()->route('event.sched');

    }
```

Comment: Can you show what the parameters contain when passed in ( mainly `daterange`, something like `echo $tempDate;`)

Comment: Hi it contains "10/14/2019 - 10/14/201910/14/2019 - 10/14/2019" I used a daterange picker to choose oct 14 as a start date and end date

Answer (score 0):

There are different way to merge date and time together. Here is two way as given below:

```
$date = new DateTime('2019-10-05');
$time = new DateTime('12:20:25');

// Solution 1, merge objects to new object:
$merge = new DateTime($date->format('Y-m-d') .' ' .$time->format('H:i:s'));
echo $merge->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // Outputs '2019-10-05 12:20:25'

echo "<br/>";

// Solution 2, update date object with time object:
$date->setTime($time->format('H'), $time->format('i'), $time->format('s'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // Outputs '2019-10-05 12:20:25'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a lot of processing of the dates and times and you can simplify it to the following.  Make sure when you say a date has a date/time, that the date is complete - your end date is only the date part, so I've added the end time as well.

```
$temp3 = explode(' - ', $tempDate);

$date1 = date_create_from_format('m/d/Y H:i:s', $temp3[0]. ' '. $time_start);
$date2 = date_create_from_format('m/d/Y H:i:s', $temp3[1]. ' '. $time_end);
echo date_format($date1, 'Y-m-d').PHP_EOL.
    date_format($date2, 'Y-m-d');
```

gives...

```
2019-10-14
2019-10-14
```

One thing to mention is that although you enter a date/time for the start and end, when you create the event - you only seem to use the date part!

Comment: oh i see then how should make it so that event_start would accept the datetime

Comment: because if i try to still do it as is and having added your suggested code i get the error date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, bool given

```  
  'event_start' => date_format($date1, 'Y-m-d'),
  'event_finish' => date_format($date2, 'Y-m-d'),
```

Comment: What do you get from `print_r($temp3);`?